# Split View App with Multiple Detail Views

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail, detailview

I'm trying to create a split view app with multiple detail view controllers. I'm having trouble with the basic setup/skeleton of the app. First I tried using xcode's Master-Detail Application template. The problem is that the classes from the template look something like this:

```m
MasterViewController.h
MasterViewController.m
DetailViewController.h
DetailViewController.m
```

But what I want is something like this:

```m
MasterViewController.h
MasterViewController.m
TitleViewController.h
TitleViewController.m
DateViewController.h
DateViewController.m
...
```

I can't figure out how to get my view controllers to load when user selects a new row.

I also tried using the sample MultipleDetailViews app from Apple, but the sample app has multiple issues for me including the fact that it uses nib files, which I don't want.

Can anyone help? Is there some tutorial about how to set up a split view app with multiple detail view controllers (without nibs)? Thank you!

*response:

Thanks! Could you post the link for the BigNerdRanch one? I couldn't find it. Also, I couldn't follow the Raywenderlich one because it uses an older version of xcode. Following your sample project, I think I'm close, but I'm getting a "terminating with uncaught exeption...". Here's what I did:

Create new project from Master-Detail template.
Add files MyTableViewController.h and MyTableViewController.m. 
In MasterViewController.m, set the number of sections to 1 and the number of rows to 2. 
In MasterViewController.h add property "MyTableViewController *myTableViewController". 
(When user clicks 1st row, detailViewController should show, when he clicks 2nd row, myTableViewController should show.) 
In MasterViewController.m, change didSelectRowAtIndexPath to:

```m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];

    if( row == 0 ) {
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.detailViewController];
        NSArray *vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self navigationController],nav, nil];
        [[self splitViewController] setViewControllers:vcs];
    }
    else {
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myTableViewController];
        NSArray *vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self navigationController],nav, nil];
        [[self splitViewController] setViewControllers:vcs];
    }
}
```

The project runs, but when I click on the 2nd row (row == 1) I get the exception.

*update 2

```m
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    int row = [indexPath row];

    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UINavigationController *detailNav = [delegate.splitController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSArray *viewControllers = nil;
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: delegate.dateController, nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: delegate.repeatController, nil];
        default:
            break;
    }

    [delegate.splitController removeFromParentViewController];
    detailNav.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    [delegate.window addSubview: delegate.splitController.view];
}
```

Comment: You should really comment under my answer. But yea, don't swap out the UINavigationController for a new UINavigationController. Once the split VC has been instantiated, I don't believe you can swap out the base VC for another one in a splitViewController. Take the navigationController that is one of the base VCs for the splitController, and set navigationController.viewControllers = @[newViewController1];. That should do the trick. Also, don't worry about the older version of Xcode, the logic is still the same in essence.

Comment: I tried to comment under your answer, but it wouldn't format my multi-line code. Anyway, I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I am now using the Raywenderlich example, which I have gotten to work. In my storyboard, the hierarchy looks like:  DetailVC<--SplitVC-->NavVC-->MasterVC. I want to swap the DetailVC without changing any of the others, so what code would I use? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of what you have, replace it with DetailVC<--NavVC<--SplitVC-->NavVC-->MasterVC. Basically, you'll hav a NavigationController on both sides and swap it's .viewControllers array. That way, the splitViewController can't complain because the viewControllers it's instantiated with are always there. The navControllers are there just as a base VC container that can swap out their viewControllers.

Comment: Ok, I set up the structure the way you said. Then I changed my didSelectRowAtIndexPath to: (see update above). The code seemed to be running correctly, but nothing was happening. Then I added the lines to remove and re-add the split VC's view to the window, and now it works, but it doesn't seem right to me. Why do I have to remove and re-add the view?

Comment: Also, even though the views are switching now, they are coming in sideways. They are in portrait even though the simulator is in landscape.

Comment: Aha! I figured it out! In order to get the new views to show I had to add this code to the app initialization: `self.window.rootViewController = self.splitController;`. Now everything works including the rotation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a great tutorial by the BigNerdRanch on how to use UISplitViewControllers. Honestly, there's no difference between using them to push a different UIViewController as the Detail or Master viewController. They just need a reference to one another and when an event happens, you push a new viewController to one side or the other. I've attached a sample project below for you to reference.

sample project: [link](https://bitbucket.org/thegamingart/nerdfeed)

Here's another tutorial on setting one up via Raywenderlich: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial)

Comment: Sample project link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

So the following happenins inside a UITableViewController which is the MasterViewController.

```js
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // 1. get the controllers from the split view [master, detail]
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            
            // 2. get nav controller for the detail  + the current storyboard
            let navigationController = controllers[controllers.count-1] as!
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            
            // 3. create the appropriate view controller (vc) then just replace the navigation controllers root vc with your new one using 'navigationController.setViewControllers([vc] ...'
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 1:
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailTableViewController") as! DetailTableViewController
                navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
            case 2:
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailCollectionViewController") as! DetailCollectionViewController
                navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
            default:
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
                navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
                break
            }
        }
```

You can do the same thing with segues. From the MasterViewController in the storyboard, drag a segue to a navigation controller and set the segue kind as a 'Show Detail (e.g. replace)'. Then from there in you didSelectRowAt you can call performSegue with identifier. Make sure that your segue has an 'Identifier'

Have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=223&v=yr3IdruL5d8)